# Finding a closed form for $\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I saw a question about proving the divergence of a function $f(n)$, defined as $\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}}$. I'm very curious if there is a closed form for $f(n)$, but I didn't manage to get anywhere after an hour.

I did not find any similar questions on the internet. Wolfram Alpha suggests that $f(n) = \binom{n+0.5}{n}$, which I verified and is true, but I have no idea how can I prove this result, and I would greatly appreciate some hints.

Thank you!

[Wolframalpha link to the function in question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+0+to+n+of+nCr%282r%2C+r%29+%2F+4%5Er)

Comment: Stirling's approximation says the summand for $n$ is $ \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \pi}} $  so your $f(n)  \approx C \sqrt n .$  grows slowly but without bound.

Comment: the thing with the $\Gamma$ function is as close as you are going to get to a closed form for the sum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's denote
$\displaystyle S_N(a)=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{1}{a^n}$

Next, we use $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2n}(x)dx=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{4^n}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$
It can be proved, for example, via direct integration:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2n}(x)dx=\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi\,4^n}\int_0^{2\pi}\big(e^{it}-e^{-it}\big)^{2n}dt$$
and noting, that $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikt}dt=2\pi$, if $\,k=0$; otherwise is zero.

Therefore,

$\displaystyle S_N(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^N\Big(\frac{4}{a}\Big)^n\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2n}(x)dx\tag*{}$

Let's denote for a while $\alpha=\frac{4}{a}$, then
$\displaystyle S_N(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha^{N+1}\sin^{{2N+2}}(x)}{1-\alpha\sin^2(x)}dx\tag*{}$
$\displaystyle \stackrel{t=\tan x}{=}\,\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-\alpha^{N+1}\Big(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\Big)^{N+1}}{1+(1-\alpha)t^2}dt\tag*{}$
For $\alpha=1$
$\displaystyle S_N(\alpha=1)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\Big(1-\Big(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\Big)^{N+1}\Big)dt\tag*{}$
Making the substitution $x=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$
$\displaystyle S_N(\alpha=1)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1\Big(x^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-x^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1-x)^{N+\frac{1}{2}}\Big)dx\tag*{}$

Using the Beta-function of negative argument (for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119506/integrate-int-0-infty-big-y-x-lambda-1-y-lambda-1-bi/4119618#4119618) )

$\displaystyle S_N(\alpha=1)=\frac{1}{\pi}\Big(B\big(-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\big)-B\big(-\frac{1}{2};N+\frac{3}{2}\big)\Big)\tag*{}$
Using
$\displaystyle B\Big(-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{\Gamma\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\big)}=0\tag*{}$

and $\Gamma\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)=-2\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$, we finally get
$\displaystyle S_N(a=4)=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^24^n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma\Big(N+\frac{3}{2}\Big)}{\Gamma(N+1)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma\Big(N+\frac{3}{2}\Big)}{N!}\tag*{}$

As a bonus, for $a>4$ we can also find $$\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{1}{a^n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+\Big(1-\frac{4}{a}\Big)t^2}=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt{a-4}}$$

Comment: Oh wow, this is way out of my depth! I did not expect this problem to be so difficult.

Comment: Nicely done! A pleasure to read.

Comment: Well done and $\to +1$ ! There is another (quicker) solution using the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: @Stefan Lafon Thank you!

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thank you! I'm not good at using the hypergeometric function ...

Answer (score 3):

We have from first principles that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S_n = \sum_{r=0}^n
\frac{1}{4^r} {2r\choose r} = \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}.}$$

Now put $1-\sqrt{1-z} = w$ so that $z=w(2-w)$ and $dz = 2(1-w)\; dw$
to get

$$\; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \; \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (2-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2} \frac{1}{1-w} 2(1-w) \\ = 2 (-1)^{n+1} \;
\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \; \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (w-2)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^2}.$$

The residue at infinity is zero by inspection so we need the residues
at $w=1$ and $w=2.$ For the former we get without the scalar in front

$$\left.\left( \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(w-2)^{n+1}}
\right)'\right|_{w=1} \\ = \left.\left(- (n+1) \frac{1}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{(w-2)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (n+1) \frac{1}{(w-2)^{n+2}}
\right)\right|_{w=1} \\= -(n+1) (-1)^{n+1} - (n+1) (-1)^{n+2} = 0.$$

With this our sum is minus the residue at $w=2.$ We write

$$2 (-1)^{n} \;\mathrm{Res}_{w=2} \frac{1}{((w-2)+2)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(w-2)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{((w-2)+1)^2} \\ = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^n}
\;\mathrm{Res}_{w=2} \frac{1}{(1+(w-2)/2)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(w-2)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+(w-2))^2}.$$

This will produce

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ S_n = \frac{1}{2^n}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose n} \frac{1}{2^q} (n-q+1).}$$

#### First piece

Now we get two pieces here, where $S_n = A_n + B_n$, the first is

$$A_n = \frac{n+1}{2^n} \; \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \; \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z/2)^{n+1}} \\ = (-1)^n 2 (n+1) \;
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \; \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{z-1}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}.$$

We evaluate this using the residues at $z=1$ and $z=2.$ We get for the
former the value $-2(n+1).$ We write for the latter

$$(-1)^n 2 (n+1) \; \mathrm{Res}_{z=2} \; \frac{1}{((z-2)+2)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-2)+1} \frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}} \\ = (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^n} \;
\mathrm{Res}_{z=2} \; \frac{1}{((z-2)/2+1)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(z-2)+1}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}$$

This yields

$$(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^n} \sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{1}{2^q} (-1)^{n-q}.$$

Simplify to obtain $A_n$. With residues adding to zero, we have
established that for the first piece $A_n$ it evaluates to $A_n =
n+1.$

#### Second piece

For the second piece we find

$$B_n = - \frac{n+1}{2^n} \sum_{q=1}^n {n+q\choose n+1} \frac{1}{2^q}
= -\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n+1+q\choose n+1}
\frac{1}{2^q} \\ = -\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \; \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \;
\frac{1}{z^n} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z/2)^{n+2}} \\ = (-1)^{n} 2
(n+1) \; \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \; \frac{1}{z^n} \frac{1}{z-1}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+2}}.$$

Again evaluate using residues at $z=1$ and $z=2.$ We get for the
former the value $2(n+1).$ For the latter we write

$$(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}} \; \mathrm{Res}_{z=2} \;
\frac{1}{((z-2)/2+1)^{n}} \frac{1}{(z-2)+1} \frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+2}}$$

This yields

$$(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n-1+q\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{1}{2^q} (-1)^{n+1-q} \\ = - \frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}
{n-1+q\choose q} \frac{1}{2^q} - \frac{n+1}{2^{2n-1}} {2n-1\choose n}
- \frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n+1}.$$

The sum is

$$- \frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}} A_{n-1} \frac{2^{n-1}}{n} = - (n+1)$$

hence piece $B_n$ evaluates as

$$\frac{n+1}{2^{2n-1}} {2n-1\choose n} + \frac{n+1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose
n+1} - (n+1).$$

#### Conclusion

Adding the two pieces we have shown that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S_n = \frac{2n+1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n} = {n+1/2\choose n}.}$$

as claimed. This may be seen from (evaluate LHS)

$$(2n+1) [z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}
= (2n+1) {-1/2\choose n} (-1)^n \\ = (2n+1)
{n-1/2\choose n} = {n+1/2\choose n}.$$